# Get Cosmos DB account primary account key/primary connection string with Azure cli/PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating an Azure DevOps release pipeline in which I want to FETCH the primary account key/primary connection string of the cosmos db account as part of an Azue CLI task and publish it as a task variable so that I can use that as parameter for the Data Factory ARM deployment activity which is a subsequent task in the same pipeline.
The code I used to fetch the key is:

```
az cosmosdb keys list \
   --name <db_account_name> \
   --resource-group <resource_group_name> \
   --subscription <subscription_name> \
   --type connection-strings \
   --query 'connectionStrings[0].connectionString' \
   --output tsv
```

The code returns

```
AccountEndpoint=https://<db_account_name>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=***;
```

**But it does not show the string content inside the account key.**

When I store this as a task variable and use the same for ARM tasks, I get error.

1. how to get the text content of the cosmos db account primary connection string/account key through Azure cli/tasks that are part of azure devops pipeline?
2. do I need to change the RBAC roles for the profile that I use to access cosmos db account from Azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the text content of the cosmos db account primary connection string/account key through azure cli/tasks that are part of azure devops pipeline?

I could not reproduce your issue, it works fine on my side, the `AccountKey` was output as plain text.

My inline script:

```
$a = az cosmosdb keys list --name joycosmostest --resource-group <groupname> --subscription <subscription-id> --type connection-strings --query 'connectionStrings[0].connectionString' --output tsv

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=connectionString;isOutput=true]$a"
```

[image]

[image]

> do I need to change the RBAC roles for the profile that I use to access cosmos db account from azure pipeline?

In Azure CLI Task, it uses the Azure Resource Manager service connection to auth Azure Service, so you should make sure the service principal used in the service connection has a correct RBAC role in your cosmos db account e.g. [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one-liner which will give you the exact primary key

```
$primaryKey = (az cosmosdb keys list --name <account_name> --resource-group <resource_group> --subscription <subscription_ID> --type keys  --output json | ConvertFrom-Json).primaryMasterKey
echo "$primaryKey"
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Ashwin.singh> ./test.ps1
gKRKaT6XQmf2dinukJit4qiymYYqMOghpdAIuoiEQhTh8VDTrkWB3XNmvyiJyMUNC4uSuwitQMBM0DanZ5Jjbw==
PS C:\Users\Ashwin.singh>
```